# Function REGEXP with a list of numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have several comma delimited lists of numbers. I need to match specific lines with a sql query. I want to build correct RegExp for this and i need your help.

Example of my rows with comma delimited lists of numbers :

- 1,8,33,44
- 1,8,44
- 1,8,22,33
- 8,22,44
- 1,88,44
- 1,22,44,66

I need to match lines that contain only numbers 8 and 44

My sql query looks like this :

```
SELECT id FROM my_list WHERE id_list REGEXP '^[0-9,]8,[0-9,]44[0-9,]$'
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You're not obliged to use mysql for this. It's not a panacea.

Comment: Refer this http://web-profile.com.ua/mysql/dev/mysql-check-if-value-is-in-comma-separated-string/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)** Function:

```
SELECT id FROM my_list WHERE FIND_IN_SET('8', id_list) AND FIND_IN_SET('44', id_list)
```

Comment: Yes, its far better than regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id FROM my_list WHERE CONCAT(",",id_list,",") REGEXP ',8,|,44,'
```